# I have a strange problem when I want to rum my app on iPhone

Tags: xcode, xcode12

[When I want to rum my app on iPhone, Illustration in the picture, please see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9PlY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using an app identifier that's already in use, try changing it for something else.